# Angular directive with $sce and $compile

Tags: angularjs, security, angular-directive

I'm making a template builder that eventually saves the html of a certain div to the DB with a bunch of inline styles and ng-click links.

I'm trying to render the saved html in the main container div with a custom directive, but I'm having problems with $sce and $compile playing nicely together.

This is my tpl directive

```
angular.module('hub').directive('tpl', ['$compile', '$parse', '$sce', function ($compile, $parse, $sce) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.tpl, function (html) {
        var parse = $sce.parseAsHtml(attrs.tpl);
        console.log(parse);//this is  function, but calling it returns undefined

        //this does not work! Just renders a blank container, no error in console
        //elem.html(parse);
        //this works, but throws an $sce error as unsafe
        elem.html($parse(attrs.tpl)(scope));
        $compile(elem.contents())(scope);
      });
    }
  }
}]);
```

And the HTML that calls the directive

```
<div id="builder-stage">
  <div id="template-container"  tpl="formData.template.markupWide">
    <div class="template-inner" style="height: 776px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can get this to work by ignoring the $sce error, but that makes me uneasy even though I'm sanitizing saved html on the server side.

Can anyone explain to me how I could get this $sce.parseAsHtml action working?

Comment: can you please create a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: I didn't get any error, can you try to reproduce it here?

Comment: assuming you fixed your own problem but how did you do it!?